# Highlight everything inside (, [, and { and expand outwards

Tags: cursor-motions, visual-mode

Suppose I have a line of text of the form `(123[456{789}abc]def)` and the cursor is inside the curly braces. In `sublime text`, we can use `ctrl-shift-m` repeatedly to jump to highlighting `789`, `{789}`, `456{789}abc`, `[456{789}abc]`, etc. Is there a way to duplicate this operation in `vim`?

EDIT: I know there are `%v%` and `vib` but they are different commands and not as fluid.

Comment: Have you tried the [vim-expand-region plugin](https://github.com/terryma/vim-expand-region)?

Comment: I think matchit's `va%a%a%` would be the logical sequence, but it doesn't work because a) matchit's `a%` is completely broken and b) matchit doesn't appear to support extension with repeated "a" objects.  Perhaps a modern replacement to matchit is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were on the first charater of the line I would do:

`f7` to jump to inside the curly braces.
`vw` to hilight 789
To contincously move outward I would do

`vi]`
`va[`
`vi)`
`va)`

But I am sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

#### Plugin [vim-matchup](https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup)

Mass has written the plugin *match-up* which allows you to press:

`v` `a%` `a%` `a%`

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

However, there are many more plugins which provide a single command to expand over different types of brackets:

- [vim-expand-region](https://github.com/terryma/vim-expand-region) `+++`
- [wildfire.vim](https://github.com/gcmt/wildfire.vim) `<CR><CR><CR>`
- [vim-sandwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich) `vababab`
- [smartpairs.vim](https://github.com/gorkunov/smartpairs.vim) `vavavav`
- [vim-textobj-delimited](https://github.com/machakann/vim-textobj-delimited) `vadadad`

A [*cloc*](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc/) comparison if you look for a lightweight plugin
[image]
(code size by number of source code and comment lines)

Please note plugins which depend on [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user) cannot be expanded, e.g. [vim-textobj-anyblock](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-textobj-anyblock). This is documented under [`:h textobj-user-known-issues`](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user/blob/master/doc/textobj-user.txt#L543-L548) (second item).